# How to map a trait without any doctrine mapping in it?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, traits

I am wondering if there is no possibility to map an existing trait without any doctrine mapping into an entity?

```
trait TimestampableTrait
{
    protected $createdAt;
    protected $updatedAt;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    use TimestampableTrait;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

I have tried the *AttributeOverride*, but it seems only to work with mapped super classes.

Is there any easy way to achieve this with annotations or do I need a yml / xml mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add Annotation within the class where you want it to be a mapped Doctrine property. Like so:

```php
trait TimestampableTrait
{
    protected $createdAt;
    protected $updatedAt;
}
```

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    use TimestampableTrait;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $createdAt;
}
```

This would still work with the getters / setters from your Trait class (if any), as the Trait is part of the class.

Comment: I hoped there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Your entity needs at least one column which acts as primary key. So either you add an ID column to your Product entity, or you add some annotations to TimestampableTrait. For example, this works:

```
trait TimestampableTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    protected $createdAt;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
final class Product
{
    use TimestampableTrait;
}
```

That produces

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    created_at VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(created_at)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If you want to change the column definition in your product class, you can use AttributeOverride like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *          name="createdAt", column=@ORM\Column(name="id")
 *     )
 * })
 */
final class Product
{
    use TimestampableTrait;
}
```

Which will produce:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Note that you cannot change the column type like this.

Comment: I have updated my question, there is of course an id property. Unfortunately I am not able to change the trait.

Comment: So you don't have any mapping on TimestampableTrait and want to create mappings for its fields in Product? The AttributeOverride annotation won't work for that, since it overrides mapping data and TimestampableTrait has none in that scenario. What you can do is either a) use XML mappings or b) override the property in Product and give it an annotation there. If you want an example, let me know, but I am unsure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Correct, there is no mapping. I can't edit the trait TimestampableTrait. I was searching for an easy way to do it with annotations without duplicating code, but it seems there is no possibility.